# C++ implicit class construction inside array initialization

Tags: c++

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int id, string name) : id(id), name(name) {}
    int id;
    string name;
};

Foo foo[] = {(1, "one"), (2, "two")};
```

This fails with "cannot convert from const char* to Foo". I assumed that `Foo` would be constructed implicitly. Is this possible? I'm using VS2010.

Comment: Try putting Foo before your ()'s

Comment: Try braces: `Foo foo[] = {{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}};`

Comment: @cppguy Putting Foo before the ()'s works, but I am trying to avoid doing so.

Comment: why? after all you are doing initialization manually

Comment: @lizusek It's more an exercise for readability's sake because I'm going to have dozens of objects in the array.

Comment: this is exactly what I mean: if you are going to have plenty of them are you really going to initialize array manually? Maybe you want a solution for automatic initilaization?

Comment: @lizusek I was planning on it. The array (to become a vector) is to hold const configuration parameters and rules that I need to iterate over. Do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use following syntax (C++11):

```
Foo foo[] = { {1, "one"}, {2, "two"}};
```

or:

```
Foo foo[] = { Foo(1, "one"), Foo(2, "two")};
```

[compiled example](http://ideone.com/R5wOp5)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following syntax in C++11:

```
Foo foo[] = { {1, "one" }, { 2, "two" } };
```

Comment: I'm using VS2010 so I can't use initialization lists. But this works well for C++11.

Comment: @Gareth If you are stuck with an old standard, better specify it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
 `Foo foo[] = {Foo(1, "one"), Foo(2, "two")};`